# Format of expiry date of cookies collected using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, cookies, pickle, strftime

I'm trying to get cookies with help of selenium, but expiry value looks quite strange, like `'expiry': 1582237071`.

How to format this value to a normal date format? Does cookies got from selenium differs from cookies got by user? I use python function:

```
driver.get_cookies()
```

Answer (score 4):

The *expiry value* you see in the cookies as **1582237071** refers to the [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)) time which can be converted to a human readable format using [`date.strftime(format)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime).

### Example

As an example, you can store the [cookies](/questions/tagged/cookies) using [pickle](/questions/tagged/pickle) while visiting an url e.g. http://www.google.com and later read the expiry of each of the cookies following the solution below:

- Code Block:

  ```
  import pickle
  import selenium.webdriver 
  import time

  driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
  driver.get("http://www.google.com")
  pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open(r'C:\Utility\testdata\my_cookies.pickle',"wb"))
  driver.quit()
  pickle_off = open(r'C:\Utility\testdata\my_cookies.pickle',"rb")
  personOut = pickle.load(pickle_off)
  print(list(personOut))
  for cookie in list(personOut):
      print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(cookie["expiry"])))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  [{'name': '1P_JAR', 'value': '2020-02-21-14', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.google.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': False, 'expiry': 1584888349}, {'name': 'NID', 'value': '198=DCEMsfy3h6nZ0vpi6p3m3J-vVJpDlUBc7ItYE99kbFtr2fssl-1nVVXqF6joPREjrW-X8yxe5PnDqMNiVaVUd0NY8S_YOfksQdb-SzKSPUP5XumjlTjyTt_C8a5XSOmpUuXnOu-JCXHDe71fTe2KC-0kwb5B7_N7wSzM6Jrozqs', 'path': '/', 'domain': '.google.com', 'secure': True, 'httpOnly': True, 'expiry': 1598107549}]
  2020-03-22 20:15:49
  2020-08-22 20:15:49
  ```

Comment: Thank you, why do you recommend pickle? What advantages does it provide?

Comment: @GeorgePhysics Dealing with cookies is easier using `pickle` which is proven and widely used. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 1):

The value that you are getting is epoch value, so you need to convert it to the normal date format.
You can do it like:

```
time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(1582237071))
```

Comment: Thank you, but, as far as I see from cookies in chrome, expire key has format of value like 2020-03-19T10:07:32.000Z, how to achieve it?

Comment: @GeorgePhysics in what format do you need the timestamp?

Comment: and what is the meaning of last 000Z?

Comment: I need it to be exactly the same, as if I got this cookies as a user without selenium

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution to get expiry of a specific cookie I wanted.
For example: I want to fetch expiry of a cookie named '__ivc'

```
all_cookies=self.driver.get_cookies();
cookies_dict = {}
       for cookie in all_cookies:
           cookies_dict[cookie['name']] = cookie['expiry'] // You can insert expiry/value/domain/priority in the value of dctionary
print(cookies_dict)
cookie_expiry=cookies_dict.get('__ivc')
print(cookie_expiry)
print(time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z', time.localtime(cookie_expiry)))
```

The output looks like this:

```
{'_ga': 1685026815, '__ivc': 1685026816, '_ga_MNGCCS5STP': 1685026815
}
1685026816
2023-05-25 20:30:16 India Standard Time
```

Comment: Adding %Z in the `.strftime` format will show the time zone selected