# How to change cookies expiry date in Python?

Tags: python, azure, cookies

I need to be authorized while using Selenium. So at the start of my tests I need to open already authorized page. Now I am using cookies with user authentication value in order to bypass login. But I see that my cookies date is only 1 week, and its mean that I need to change cookies manually every week. Its not an accepted approach, so I want to make my cookies with no expiration period or set date as a possible max date. Now my json file looks like below:

```
{
        "domain": "somdomain",
        "expiry": 1659372517, # its very complicated to me read this value, but if I am checking it from browser I see that expiration date is only 1 week. 
        "name": "somename",
        "value": "somevalue
    }
```

I have tried to change expiry date manually but it is not working. How can I change it? Is it possible or not? Also, if it is possible help me to understan how can I decode the date value, because I can't got it....

Please note that I am tried to bypass login to Microsoft/Azure account. I am using Python + Selenium.

Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The cookie is set to expire server-side (Azure probably defaults or uses a week maximum for their sessions). Manually changing the `expiry` field on Selenium's side is not going to do anything about that. And the `expiry` value is in Unix Epoch Time, so if you want to make it easier to read, you can use (in Python) something like the following: `import datetime; print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1659372517).strftime("%A %B %d %Y %I:%M:%S"))` which prints `Monday August 01 2022 12:48:37`. If you have the `date` command on your CLI, you can do `date -d "@1659372517"`.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering both my questions. So, as far as I understood there no way to change the date and I need manually change the value instead every week, right?

Comment: [Format of expiry date of cookies collected using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60337698/format-of-expiry-date-of-cookies-collected-using-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

*As suggested by @wiki an as per your understanding yes you need to change the date value manually using python.*
*Here is the command to print the datetime*

```
import datetime;
print (datetime.datetime.fronttimestamp(165372517).strftime("%A %B %D %Y %I:%M:%S"))
```

*and if you have date command then you can use below command in CLI*

```
date -d "@165372517"
```

*Here is the [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67690756/15969833) thread that you can refer for collecting expiry date format using selenium.*